# Выборка точек в радиусе 3 км. от координат в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lat   | double  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lon   | double  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Помогите сделать выборку данных, в радиусе 3км. от определенных координат.

Comment: Формула расчёта расстояния - не секрет (её вообще лучше оформить как UDF). Предварительно - отбирайте те точки, что по обоим координатам отклоняются не более 3 км, для снижения вычислительной нагрузки.

Answer (score 0):

поскольку расстояние не очень велико по сравнению с радиусом Земли, то можно использовать упрощённую формулу (вам же не с точностью до миллиметра?):

```
R = 6371
x = (lon2 - lon1) * cos((lat2 + lat1) / 2)
y = (lat2 - lat1)
d = R * sqrt(x * x + y * y)
```

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

сравнивать точнее квадраты, чем корни, поэтому

```
d^2 = R^2 * (x * x + y * y)
```

значит нужна такая формула для выборки

```
40589641 * ((lon_s - lon) * cos((lat_s + lat) / 2) * (lon_s - lon) * cos((lat_s + lat) / 2) + (lat_s - lat) * (lat_s - lat)) < 9
```

т.е. запрос будет типа такого:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    table
where
    40589641 * ((@lon_s - lon) * COS((@lat_s + lat) / 2) * (@lon_s - lon) * COS((@lat_s + lat) / 2) + (lat_s - lat) * (lat_s - lat)) < 9
```

Comment: По вашей формуле один градус широты равен одному градусу долготы? Тогда погрешность должна быть больше 60%.

Comment: @DiD, один градус - это свыше 100км, когда надо найти в радиусе 3км, то уж 100км и 3км точно не совпадут :) поэтому я и написал, что можно использовать приближенную формулу. Но вообще можно подсчитать какая погрешность около 3 километров

Comment: Я имел в виду, что по широте их 180 (от -90 до +90) а по долготе их 360 (от -180 до +180).